Getting "Not a proxy instance" error when mocking ClientProxy.getClient() in unit tests
I am writing a unit test for a method that creates a proxy using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and sets up some properties. However, I'm encountering a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance error when attempting to mock the ClientProxy.getClient() method.
Here is my class under test:
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

public class MyClassUnderTest {
    private String endpointAddress;
    private String serviceName;

    public MyService myServiceCreateProxy() {
        MyService result = null;
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxy = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        proxy.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
        proxy.setAddress(endpointAddress);
        proxy.setServiceName(new QName(serviceName));
        proxy.setEndpointName(new QName("http://example/MyService", "MyServicePort"));
        proxy.setBindingId(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
        proxy.getOutInterceptors().add(mySecurityInterceptor());
        result = (MyService) proxy.create();
        ClientProxy.getClient(result).getOutInterceptors().add(new MyRequestInterceptor());
        HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(result).getConduit();
        conduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(300000);
        conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(300000);
        return result;
    }

    private MyRequestInterceptor mySecurityInterceptor() {
        return new MyRequestInterceptor();
    }
}


Test Class:
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.mockito.Answers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryMock;

    @Mock
    private MyService myServiceMock;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private Client clientMock;

    @Mock
    private HTTPConduit httpConduitMock;

    @Mock
    private MyRequestInterceptor myRequestInterceptorMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(proxyFactoryMock.create()).thenReturn(myServiceMock);
        when(ClientProxy.getClient(myServiceMock)).thenReturn(clientMock);
        when(clientMock.getConduit()).thenReturn(httpConduitMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyServiceCreateProxy() {
        MyService result = classUnderTest.myServiceCreateProxy();

        assertNotNull(result);
        verify(proxyFactoryMock).setAddress(anyString());
        verify(proxyFactoryMock).setServiceClass(MyService.class);
        verify(proxyFactoryMock).setBindingId(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
        verify(clientMock.getOutInterceptors()).add(any(MyRequestInterceptor.class));
        verify(httpConduitMock.getClient()).setConnectionTimeout(300000);
        verify(httpConduitMock.getClient()).setReceiveTimeout(300000);
    }
}


When running the test, I encounter the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:127)
    ...


The error occurs at this line in the setUp method:
when(ClientProxy.getClient(myServiceMock)).thenReturn(clientMock);


It seems that myServiceMock is not being recognized as a proxy instance, which is required for ClientProxy.getClient() to work.
How can I properly mock the ClientProxy.getClient() method to avoid the not a proxy instance error in my unit test? Is there a better approach to testing this method that involves JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and ClientProxy?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you. But when I try to do this with PowerMockito and BDDMockito like they mention in the article, I get a NullPointerException.

I integrate classes from third party packages via service/wrapper classes. If the interfaces are implemented, I can also swap classes and thus functionality.
Above all, it makes mocking easier, especially when it comes to static method calls.
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;

public class ClientProxyService implements ClientProxyServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public Client getClient(Object object) {
        return ClientProxy.getClient(object);
    }
}

public interface ClientProxyServiceInterface {
    Client getClient(Object object);
}


ClientProxyService clientProxyServiceMock = mock(ClientProxyService.class);
when(clientProxyServiceMock.getClient(myServiceMock)).thenReturn(clientMock);


This is good advice. Also known as “don’t mock types you don’t own”.
